# How to add description of my error to perror function

Tags: c, error-handling, errno

How can I add an error to the perror stack?

here is an example of what I want

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int Div (int a, int b, int * c) {
   if (b == 0) {
       // add to perror: "cannot divide by zero!"
       return 0;
   }
   *c = a / b;
   return 1;
}

int main () {
   int n;
   if (!Div(2, 0, &n)) {
      perror("could not divide");
   }
   return 1;
}
```

Comment: That's not at AAAAAAAAAAAAALLLL how the errno subsystem works...

Comment: If this is C++.. **use exceptions!!**

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: how *does* it work?  I'm curious about that too :-)

Comment: Removed the C++ tag for you..

Comment: @Nathan: You fill `errno`, and `perror()` adds more flavor than "stuff blew up". See the `perror(3)` man page for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard (or nonstandard, on the systems I'm aware of) way to add new `errno` values; you can assign to `errno` to use existing values, but this is not a good idea for anything not part of the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

The only way is to change the C standard library, and you don't want to do that.

If you change `libc` and use the modified one, you can add your own `errno` numbers. But then your program will only work correctly on systems with your modified "standard" library.